# Suggestions for coding AI algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

What I'm trying to do is make a battleships game, but I'm stuck at the ships placement algorithm for the AI. The board itself is a 2d array of objects. Here's what I have for now:

```
pickFirstCell() {
    let selectCol = () => {
      let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.npcSelectionField.length);
      let selectCell = () => {
        let cellIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.npcSelectionField[colIndex].length);
        if (this.npcSelectionField[colIndex][cellIndex].isEmpty === false) {
          selectCell();
        } else {
          this.npcSelectionField[colIndex][cellIndex].isEmpty = false;
          this.pickDirection(this.npcSelectionField, colIndex, cellIndex);
        }

      }

      selectCell();
    }

    selectCol();
}
```

The above function picks a random cell on the board

```
pickDirection(field, col, cell) {
  let neighbors = [].concat(
    (field[col + 1] || [])[cell] || [],
    (field[col - 1] || [])[cell] || [],
    (field[col] || [])[cell + 1] || [],
    (field[col] || [])[cell - 1] || []
  );

  let randDir = () => {
    let randIndex = neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random() * neighbors.length)];
    if (randIndex.isEmpty === false) {
      randDir();
    } else {
      randIndex.isEmpty = false;
    }
  }

  randDir();

}
```

which is followed by another function that finds the selected cells' neighboring cells and randomly picks one. This works great for placing ships of 2 cell dimensions.

The issue I'm having is going further and making the AI choose ships for 3, 4 and 5 cell dimensions, but I'm stuck on ideas. Should I change the existing algorithm or is it possible to continue with what I already have?

Any kind of input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your approach is correct. Do you have any code that renders where the ships are placed? Without that it might be difficult to see if the changes made to your function are correct or not.

Comment: Yes, I'm using angular to add css classes based on the objects property values. The changes are being rendered on the board.